# What is the difference between DNS Conditional forwarder and forwarder in Active Directory DNS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns

I am using Amazon workspaces and I want to forward queries all my internet based queries to an internet based DNS, however there are also my corporate domains which can only be resolved using the on-premises data centre DNS.

I found out about conditional forwarders, but I cannot use * in that to send all Public domains to the internet based DNS service and at the same time there is confusion with the forwarders which have been configured as 169.254.169.253 in the amazon managed active directory dns servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditional forwarder can be used to send queries related to certain domains to your specific domain name server,whereas forwarder is used to forward all the queries from AD DNS to the domain name server.

In your case you would want to configure a conditional forwarder for your corporate domain names let say corp.example.com pointing to the on-prem DNS servers.For all other domains you will be using the DNS forwarder which can be one or more DNS server to which you want to forward the DNS queries.

A detailed example for a similar setup is on this site  http://thebetternetwork.com/aws/how-to-use-split-dns-traffic-across-on-prem-and-private-hosted-zone-for-amazon-workspaces/ . Instead of private hosted zone ,you will point your corp domain name to the on-prem dns server.